# Cache Expiration Implementation using NSCache

Tags: cocoa-touch, caching

I am using NSCache to implement caching in my app.  I want to add expiration to it so it will obtain new data after some time.  What are the options and what's the best approach?

Should I look at the timestamp when the cache is accessed and invalidate it then? Should the cache automatically invalidate itself by using a fixed interval timer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Should the cache automatically invalidate itself by using a fixed
>   interval timer?

This would be a bad solution, because you might add something seconds before the timer fires.  The expiry should be based on the specific item's age. (It would, of course, be possible to *conditionally* invalidate items using a timer; see the comments on this answer.)

Here's an example.  I thought about subclassing `NSCache`, but decided it was simpler to use composition.

#### Interface

```
//
//  ExpiringCache.h
//
//  Created by Aaron Brager on 10/23/13.

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol ExpiringCacheItem <NSObject>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *expiringCacheItemDate;

@end

@interface ExpiringCache : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSCache *cache;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimeInterval expiryTimeInterval;

- (id)objectForKey:(id)key;
- (void)setObject:(NSObject <ExpiringCacheItem> *)obj forKey:(id)key;

@end
```

#### Implementation

```
//
//  ExpiringCache.m
//
//  Created by Aaron Brager on 10/23/13.

#import "ExpiringCache.h"

@implementation ExpiringCache

- (instancetype) init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.cache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
        self.expiryTimeInterval = 3600;  // default 1 hour
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)objectForKey:(id)key {
    @try {
        NSObject <ExpiringCacheItem> *object = [self.cache objectForKey:key];

        if (object) {
            NSTimeInterval timeSinceCache = fabs([object.expiringCacheItemDate timeIntervalSinceNow]);
            if (timeSinceCache > self.expiryTimeInterval) {
                [self.cache removeObjectForKey:key];
                return nil;
            }
        }

        return object;
    }

    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (void)setObject:(NSObject <ExpiringCacheItem> *)obj forKey:(id)key {
    obj.expiringCacheItemDate = [NSDate date];
    [self.cache setObject:obj forKey:key];
}

@end
```

#### Notes

- Assumes you're using ARC.
- I didn't implement `setObject:forKey:cost:` since the NSCache documentation [all but tells you not to use it](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCache/setObject:forKey:cost:).
- I use a @try/@catch block, since technically you could add an object to the cache that doesn't respond to `expiringCacheItemDate`.  I thought about using `respondsToSelector:` for this, but you could add an object that doesn't respond to that too, since NSCache takes `id` and not `NSObject`.

#### Sample code

```
#import "ExpiringCache.h"

@property (nonatomic, strong) ExpiringCache *accountsCache;

- (void) doSomething {
    if (!self.accountsCache) {
        self.accountsCache = [[ExpiringCache alloc] init];
        self.accountsCache.expiryTimeInterval = 7200; // 2 hours
    }

    // add an object to the cache
    [self.accountsCache setObject:newObj forKey:@"some key"];

    // get an object
    NSObject *cachedObj = [self.accountsCache objectForKey:@"some key"];
    if (!cachedObj) {
        // create a new one, this one is expired or we've never gotten it
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't look like an eviction policy. Resources are being evicted if expired, only on access attempts. Instances may live forever, even if expired.

Comment: @RaduSimionescu True. You could add a timer to periodically evict expired objects if that's needed. (Or one timer for each expiry time if you want to be even stricter.) However, since `NSCache` will evict objects when there's memory pressure, it might be OK to let them sit indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to set an expire time when setting an object and compare against the expire time for an object.

For example:

**Usage**

```
#import "PTCache.h"

NSInteger const PROFILE_CACHE_EXPIRE = 3600;

- (void) cacheSomething: (id) obj
                 forKey: (NSString*) key
{
     [PTCache sharedInstance] setObject: obj
                                 forKey: key
                                 expire: PROFILE_CACHE_EXPIRE
     ];

}
```

**Interface**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface PTCache : NSCache

+ (PTCache *) sharedInstance;

- (void) setObject: (id) obj
            forKey: (NSString *) key
            expire: (NSInteger) seconds;

- (id) objectForKey: (NSString *) key;

@end
```

**Implementation**

```
#import "PTCache.h"

@implementation PTCache
{
    NSMutableArray * expireKeys;
}


+ (PTCache *) sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t predicate = 0;
    __strong static id sharedObject = nil;
    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedObject;
}

- (id) init
{
    if ( self = [super init])
    {
        expireKeys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

/**
 * Get Object
 *
 * @param NSString * key
 * @return id obj
 *
 **/

- (id) objectForKey: (NSString *) key
{
    id obj = [super objectForKey: key];

    if( obj == nil)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    BOOL expired = [self hasExpired: key];

    if( expired)
    {
        [super removeObjectForKey: key];
        return nil;
    }

    return obj;
}

/**
 * Set Object
 *
 * @param id obj
 * @param NSString * key
 * @param NSInteger seconds
 *
 */
- (void) setObject: (id) obj
            forKey: (NSString *) key
            expire: (NSInteger) seconds
{
    [super setObject: obj forKey: key];

    [self updateExpireKey: key expire: seconds];
}


/**
 * Update Expire Time for Key and Seconds to Expire
 *
 * @param NSString * key
 * @param NSInteger seconds
 *
 **/
- (void) updateExpireKey: (NSString *) key
                  expire: (NSInteger) seconds
    __block NSInteger index = -1;

    [expireKeys enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if([obj[@"key"] isEqualToString: key])
        {
            index = idx;
            *stop = YES;
            return;
        }
    }];

    NSNumber * expires = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] + seconds)];

    if( index > -1)
    {
        [[expireKeys objectAtIndex: index] setObject: expires forKey: key];
    }
    else
    {
        NSMutableDictionary * element = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [element setObject: key forKey: @"key"];
        [element setObject: expires forKey: @"expire"];

        [expireKeys addObject: element];
    }

}

/**
 * Has Expired for Key
 *
 **/
- (BOOL) hasExpired: (NSString *) key
{
    NSNumber * expiredObj = [self getExpireTime: key];

    NSDate * current = [NSDate date];

    NSDate * expireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: [expiredObj doubleValue]];

    return [current compare: expireDate] == NSOrderedDescending;
}

/**
 * Get Expire Time
 *
 * @param NSString * key
 * @param NSInteger
 *
 **/

- (NSNumber *) getExpireTime: (NSString *) key
{
    __block NSNumber * expire = nil;

    [expireKeys enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if([obj[@"key"] isEqualToString: key])
        {
            expire = obj[@"expire"];
            *stop = YES;
            return;
        }
    }];

    return expire;
}



@end
```