# How to Implement Time-based NSCache with setObject Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, nscache

I have an `NSDictionary` which I cached. I need to implement a time-based setObject with timestamp. `NSCache Class` doesn't have a setExpiry. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the extension I have so far:

```
import Foundation

extension NSCache {

class var sharedInstance : NSCache {
    struct Static {
        static let instance : NSCache = NSCache()
    }
    return Static.instance
 }
}
```

I found `NSCache Extension` at http://nshipster.com/nscache/ . Any easy way to implement with an expiry timestamp?

```
extension NSCache {
subscript(key: AnyObject) -> AnyObject? {
    get {
        return objectForKey(key)
    }
    set {
        if let value: AnyObject = newValue {
            setObject(value, forKey: key)
        } else {
            removeObjectForKey(key)
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: A little off-topic, but if you're trying to create a singleton by what you have in the extension right now, you should check out [this article] (http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton). You can create a singleton in one line, like this: `static let sharedInstace = NSCache()`.

Comment: I have a JSON, which I need to cache it with expiry timestamp of 1HR. Do you think my approach is sufficient? Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a timer to empty the queue:

```
private let ExpiringCacheObjectKey = "..."
private let ExpiringCacheDefaultTimeout: NSTimeInterval = 60

class ExpiringCache : NSCache {

    /// Add item to queue and manually set timeout
    ///
    /// - parameter obj: Object to be saved
    /// - parameter key: Key of object to be saved
    /// - parameter timeout: In how many seconds should the item be removed

    func setObject(obj: AnyObject, forKey key: AnyObject, timeout: NSTimeInterval) {
        super.setObject(obj, forKey: key)
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeout, target: self, selector: "timerExpires:", userInfo: [ExpiringCacheObjectKey : key], repeats: false)
    }

    // Override default `setObject` to use some default timeout interval

    override func setObject(obj: AnyObject, forKey key: AnyObject) {
        setObject(obj, forKey: key, timeout: ExpiringCacheDefaultTimeout)
    }

    // method to remove item from cache

    func timerExpires(timer: NSTimer) {
        removeObjectForKey(timer.userInfo![ExpiringCacheObjectKey] as! String)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Rob, I get a potential error, can you please help? [Screenshot] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/d9wocj6dzex380j/Screenshot%202015-11-08%2016.09.24.png?dl=0)   This is what I think should be the syntax removeObjectForKey(timer.userInfo![ExpiringCacheObjectKey]) ?

Comment: Do not add a timer for every key in your cache, you should add an expiration date to the key and check it when you retrieve the object.

Comment: But if you don't retrieve the object, then the cache won't be purged like the OP wanted. You could, though, have a single repeating timer that iterates through all of the objects in the cache and determine which, if any, need to be purged. Also, if you're doing something like that, I'd pursue a generic that captures the "last retrieved" time rather than embedding it in the key. Frankly, I think the entire time-based purging idea is over-engineered and I'd just stick with `countLimit` and `totalCostLimit`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the basic approach.

**PS:** I  haven't tested this code and I wrote it in the text editor. It may require some tweaks depending on your requirements :)

```swift
import Foundation

protocol Cacheable: class {
    var expiresAt : NSDate { get set }
}

class CacheableItem : Cacheable {
    var expiresAt = NSDate()
}

extension NSCache {

    subscript(key: AnyObject) -> Cacheable? {
        get {
            if let obj = objectForKey(key) as? Cacheable {
                 var now = NSDate();
                if  now.isGreaterThanDate(obj.expiresAt) {
                    removeObjectForKey(key)
                }
            }

            return objectForKey(key) as? Cacheable
        }
        set {
            if let value = newValue {
                setObject(value, forKey: key)
            } else {
                removeObjectForKey(key)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension NSDate
{
    func isGreaterThanDate(dateToCompare : NSDate) -> Bool
    {
        var isGreater = false

        if self.compare(dateToCompare) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending {
            isGreater = true
        }

        return isGreater
    }
}
```

Based on [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19553760/1163224).

Comment: Great thanks! Will test it and see how to works.. Cheers :)

Comment: @TalZion I just made an edit to the answer, so the code actually compiles.

Comment: @TalZion I've edit my answer. correct logical error in comparing dates. Hope it works for you :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help :)!. I tried to test it, how would I work with it? When I setObject, how would I add the expiry date timestamp?

Comment: You can assign the expiration date before adding to the cache like var myCacheableItem = new CacheableItem() => myCacheableItem.expiresAt   = myCacheableItem.expiresAt.dateByAddingTimeInterval(3600.0)
=> cache.set(value: myCacheableItem, key: "image.png")